# SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "foreign"

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Ao criar essa tabela no postgre sql
recebo essa mensagem de erro

Criacao da tabela `tipo_agendamento_escritorio`

```
create table tipo_agendamento_escritorio(
    id int8 not null,
    primary key (id),
    tipo_agendamento_id int8 not null,
    constraint foreign key (tipo_agendamento_id) REFERENCES tipo_agendamento (id),
    prazocomum int8 not null,
    prazotrabalhista int8 not null,
    tempoconfeccao int8 not null
);
create sequence tipo_agendamento_escritorio_id_seq;
```

Recebo a mensagem de erro:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "foreign"

Comment: "Acho" que tá sobrando um `constraint` ali. Ela seria usada caso estivesse adicionando a chave estrangeira posterior à criação da tabela (query distinta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifique:

```
create table tipo_agendamento_escritorio(
    id int8 not null,
    primary key (id),
    tipo_agendamento_id int8 not null REFERENCES tipo_agendamento (id),
    prazocomum int8 not null,
    prazotrabalhista int8 not null,
    tempoconfeccao int8 not null
);
create sequence tipo_agendamento_escritorio_id_seq;
```

ou, se quiser declarar separadamente (table constraint), coloque um nome da constraint após o termo CONSTRAINT:

```
constraint um_nome_qualquer foreign key (tipo_agendamento_id) REFERENCES tipo_agendamento (id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Faltou o nome da `constraint`:

```
...
constraint nome_constraint foreign_key (tipo_agendamento_id) REFERENCES tipo_agendamento (id),
...
```

Ou inibir a palavra `constraint`

```
...
foreign_key (tipo_agendamento_id) REFERENCES tipo_agendamento (id),
...
```